# Django not finding templates

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm trying to set up a Django app for a project, but I'm having trouble with the templates folder being found. Here is my layout...

```
-Alexa  
   -Alexa  
      -__init__.py  
      -settings.py
      -urls.py
      -wsgi.py
   -AlexaApp
      -migrations
      -static
         -css
         -js
      -templates
         -login.html
      -__init__.py
      -admin.py
      -apps.py
      -models.py
      -tests.py
      -views.py
   -manage.py
```

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Alexa',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Alexa.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'templates/login.html'}),
    url(r'^logout/', auth_views.logout),
]
```

I've tried adding `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')` to my TEMPLATES DIRS, but that didn't help. I've also tried adding `'Alexa'` and `'AlexaApp'` to my INSTALLED_APPS as well. I've also tried changing the `'templates/login.html'` to a direct path the template folder with no success. I'm sure it's something simple, but not sure where I'm messing up. I'm using Django 1.11.5. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!
Dylan

Comment: Would need a touch more information. What is your BASE_DIR resolving to? My guess is that it's to your root `Alexa` directory, which means Django would be looking in `\Alexa\templates` which doesn't exist. Or it might be resolving to `\Alexa\Alexa` which means it would be looking for templates under there.

Comment: Ah! I missed that part when I copied and pasted.. Just updated the question! Right now it is set to `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`. I also moved my templates folder to `\Alexa\Alexa\templates\` but it still wouldn't pick it up.

Comment: So, your BASE_DIR is using the settings.py file as the `__file__` argument, which means the nested dirname/dirname will return your root 'Alexa' directory. Try '\Alexa\templates' and then your login `template_name` would just be login.html.

Comment: You shouldn't usually add `Alexa` to your installed apps because it's the project directory that contains settings, not an app. You should however add `AlexaApp` to your  installed apps if you want to use its models, templates or other contents.

Comment: @MikeTheReader That was it! I just had to leave it as `login.html`, and then added `'AlexaApp'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`. @Alasdair, adding `'AlexaApp'` was the other half of the fix! Thank you both!

Comment: @DForsyth I noticed you unaccepted my answer. If there's any inaccuracy in it, let me know and I'll amend it for posterity. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `AlexaApp` to `installed_apps` for django to look for templates inside `AlexaApp/templates/`. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#app-dirs).

Then access your template like this:

```
 'template_name': 'login.html'
```